# Is it possible to turn on "read receipts" in iMessage for just certain contacts?

Tags: iphone, ios, messages

I am wondering if it is possible to specify which of my contacts will see if I have read their messages. I know I can turn on "send read receipts" in iMessage but that allows everyone to see if I have read their messages. I would really like it if there was some way to just have certain of my friends see that I have read their messages.

Comment: Any insight to this question would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Almost 2 years later, still no support for this :(

Comment: The jailbreak community seems to have made a [tweak](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2013/03/07/selectivereading-allows-you-to-select-who-receives-imessage-read-receipts/) that allows this. Not sure if it's still maintained though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible at this time. Read receipts in iMessage appears to be an all-on or all-off option only.

Comment: That is already very obvious, I am just wondering if there is any other info out there that would allow me to do what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is core iOS functionality. Aside from looking for jailbreak-community mods (which may or may not exist) or writing your own modification (would require jailbreak) you're gonna have to wait for Apple to decide to include this feature (which they may never).

Answer (score 1):

Individual read receipt assignment is coming in iOS 9, for what it's worth.

Comment: Excuse me, can you provide more details on this? I'm using iOS 9 (Public Beta 2) and there is no such thing as individual read receipt.

Comment: I'm not sure it's available in the betas (yet), but it was shown and discussed in several WWDC panels as an iOS 9 feature this year.

Comment: Now that iOS 9 is out - could you edit this to explain how to implement this? I've looked at the documentation and can't seem to find this setting...